# Hosting of a Jar file

Tags: java, jar, war

I have a jar file which contains two Java classes. Using the javamail API I have developed these classes to read and edit my mail, then send to another mail id.

I am able to execute this through my standalone system via Eclipse. Now I want to host this jar file somewhere remotely so that it would fetch the data in real time and execute the job regularly. I have contacted couple of hosting sites and they are saying that they require a war file instead.

Does anyone have any suggestions to this problem?

Comment: Your problem is that you've contacted web hosting providers, and you don't have a web application. The good news is if you can run it on your own system then you can run it on a dedicated server or VPS. Linode, Rackspace Cloud, heck, even DreamHost does VPS now. Take your pick!

Answer (score 2):

To give you another point of view and to be constructive, I would go with embedding your jar into a war application and you get some things for free, the most important I think is that you gain a managed application lifecycle so with a standard web application context listener you can start and stop your program in a managed way. Besides you have more hosting options and it is less work.

Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know of any services specifically for plain execution of executables, your best bet is probably getting a cheap VPS. With some searching you can probably find one that would work for around $5 USD/month. For a single simple app you'd only need around 128MB of memory.

Pick one up, install Java (whatever Linux distro you get probably has OpenJDK in the repositories), copy your files over, and set up a cron job to run the executable at a set interval.

For easier administration, install something like [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) and use that to configure the cron job. The command would likely just be `java -jar /path/to/my/App.jar`, and you can use the web interface to configure the intervals for the command to be executed.

For an app like this, I would avoid anything related to a war file. You aren't making an application with a web interface (like a PHP app or some such) so it really wouldn't be appropriate. You would have to write some extra code to make it compatible with a container like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), and on top of that the memory requirements for running the application server would be a lot higher.